# Proxy goes to http insted https via nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have configured nginx to make reverse proxy both request over 80 and 443 to an Apache Server on 443. But it does not work,

My config is:

```
    server {
    
        listen 192.168.50.55:80;
        listen 192.168.50.55:443 ssl;
        server_name groupware.example.com;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors example.com cloud.example.com";
    
        ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/groupware.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/groupware.example.com/privkey.pem;
    
        ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        server_name_in_redirect on;
        proxy_set_header Host groupware.example.com;
    
        access_log            /var/log/nginx/groupware.log;
    
        location / {
    
          proxy_set_header        Host $host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_pass          https://groupware.example.com;
          proxy_read_timeout  90;
           
        }

   location ~ .well-known {

                 root /srv/web;
        }

  }
```

This is the output of curl -I http://groupware.example.com:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.14.2
Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 13:26:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Location: http://groupware.example.com/something
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors example.com cloud.example.com
```

**EDIT 1**

I have the following line on configuration of Apache Virtual Host (upstream):

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'groupware.example.com'">
    RedirectMatch ^/$ https:/groupware.example/something
</If>
```

Why request to http:// are not going to https:// of the proxied server?

Comment: Why do you think that the request was not proxied? There is nothing in your post to indicate that it was not proxied correctly.

Comment: you're right is proxied, but why request goes to http:// and not to https:// ?

Comment: It looks like the 302 redirect is coming from upstream. So you need to look there.

Comment: And anyway, it looks like you don't want it to be https (though I can't figure out why).

Comment: I've edited the question relative to upstream. Perhaps, I'm wrong, but why if proxy_pass has https:// why the request goes to http:/ ?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I've just sent it

Comment: You really need to clarify what exactly you are trying to accomplish with this strange setup. Why are you answering on http and not redirecting to https? Why are you proxying to https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've splitted the configuration one for http and another one for https, so adding a new file. And commentting out `listen 192.168.50.35:80;`

The new file is something as follows:

```
server {

    listen 192.168.50.55:80;
    server_name groupware.example.com;


    access_log            /var/log/nginx/groupware-80.log;

    location /  {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass          http://groupware.example.com;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;
    }



  }
```

And let the work of redirection from http to https to upstream (Apache).

Comment: It is best to let nginx do the redirect from http to https.

Comment: And keeping the "reverse proxying"? I had a lot of pain trying to do that. What would be the benefits that nginx does it? I hope http clients (on a internal network)  that accesses to upstream, directly without nginx...

Comment: Ah, you left out some essential information from the original question. Yes, it is best to handle all clients the same way in the configuration, that way the overall configuration is simpler. Actually it looks like you need a VPN setup, not a reverse proxy. That is more appropriate for "share the intranet" use case.

Comment: In fact I've already have a vpn, reverse proxy  because I have only a public address.